# Is there a weather app that can be moved to an SD card, with a separate widget program?

Tags: app2sd, weather

In know some apps offer separate widget apps so you can move the main app to the SD card.  Is there any weather apps designed like this?  I haven't been able to find one, so does anyone know if one exists?

Comment: You can move any of them to SD card... only their Widgets wouldn't work.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Edited the question to take that into account.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Are you sure 'bout that? I know that I can on my CM device, but I have that s2e app installed which allows me to. Can you store any app to your SD card by default?

Comment: @Steven For "by Default" thing, there's a glitch... the question is asking different thing.

Comment: @Steven And, that statement was for weather apps.. There are other things than widgets which can screw things up..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate widget app may be available in case when wigdet covers only a small subset of the main application functionality. However, for the weather app and weather app widget the main difference is the screen representation, the processing routines are almost the same. I'm sorry to say, but it's very unlikely to find the weather application with the separate widget.

Moreover, with the Froyo/Eclair moving into the obsolescence quite steady and newer version of Android having "unlimited" app storage in the range of 8-16GB, it's very unlikely the new developers will ever be inclined to make that kind of widget app.

Comment: What do you mean by unlimited app storage?  You can only store as much as you have room for, unless you don't have to store the app on your phone.

Comment: by "unlimited app storage" I meant "any contemporary android device comes equipped with 8-16GB of internal storage, where you may store your programs, which renders completely unnecessary moving content to SD or vice versa"